# Ignore portion of Where Clause if Variable is Null

Tags: sql, excel, string, where-clause, powerquery

I am looking for a way for my Where Clause in PowerQuery / SQL Statement to ignore NULL parameter values.  I currently assign 4 different variables using Text.Combine to pull from an excel table.  This works great but if any of the 4 variables are left blank, I get no results.  Is it possible to ignore the p.partnumber portion of the Where Clause if SKUList is Null for example?

4 Variables:

```
SKUList = Text.Combine(#"tMultiSKU"[SKU List],"','"),
ItemTypeName = Text.Combine(#"tItemType"[Item Type Name],"','"),
ItemStatus = Text.Combine(#"tItemStatus"[Item Status],"','"),
Orderability = Text.Combine(#"tOrderability"[Orderability],"','")
```

Where Clause:

```
WHERE 
p.partnumber in ('"& SKUList & "')
AND s.ItemTypeName in('" & ItemTypeName & "')
AND p.itemstatusname in('"& ItemStatus & "')
AND p.OrderabilityFlag in('"& Orderability &"')
```

Comment: `where (p.partnumber in ('"& SKUList & "') or SKUist is null) ... `?

Comment: I get an invalid column name error when I add SKUList like that:DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Invalid column name 'SKUList'.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=SQL
    Message=Invalid column name 'SKUList'.
    Number=207
    Class=16

Comment: This looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to disable filter predicates when given an empty value.

You can use boolean logic. Assuming that you mean *empty string* (not `null` value), you would phrase the `where` clause as:

```
    WHERE 
        ('" & ItemTypeName & "' = '' OR s.ItemTypeName     = '" & ItemTypeName & "')
    AND ('" & ItemStatus   & "' = '' OR p.itemstatusname   = '" & ItemStatus   & "')
    AND ('" & Orderability & "' = '' OR p.OrderabilityFlag = '" & Orderability & "')
```

Note that I changed the `IN` condition to a simple equality, since that's what you seem to want.

This can easily be changed to handle `null` values instead, like:

```
('" & ItemTypeName & "' IS NULL OR s.ItemTypeName = '" & ItemTypeName & "')
```

Comment: so close!  The empty string works great when there is only 1 choice.  Once i add multiple values to query, it breaks down.  The Where Needs the IN to add the ' on both ends of the SKUList.  The Text.Combine creates the multiple choices like 123','456 but the sql needs it to look like '123','456'.

Comment: @JaredJohnson: ok, so you need `IN`. Like so: `('" & ItemTypeName & "' = '' OR s.ItemTypeName  IN (" & ItemTypeName & "))`? (I removed the single quotes around the parameter).

Comment: I am still getting and error and I am not sure were the ',' is located other than in the Text.Combine Function.                                                                    
DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=SQL

    Message=An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
    Number=4145
    Class=15          ('" & SKUList & "' = '' OR p.partnumber IN (" & SKUList & "))

Comment: Why am I getting An Expression of non-boolean type error? `WHERE 
p.itemstatusname in('"& ItemStatus & "')
AND ('" & SKUList & "' = '' OR p.partnumber IN('"& SKUList &"'))
AND p.OrderabilityFlag in('"& Orderability &"')"]),`  When SKUList is blank, it works but when I add Values to SKUList, I get this error.